# codeigniter search with join table

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, join

this is my controller

```
function search_keyword()
{
    $cari    =   $this->input->GET('cari');
    $data['dapat']    =   $this->order_test_m->search($cari);
    $this->load->view('admin/a',$data);
}
```

this is my model

```
    function search($cari)
    {
        $this->db->from("uhd_user_order AS t1");
        $this->db->join("uhd_user_product_order AS t2", "t1.user_order_id = t2.user_order_id");
        $this->db->where('user_order_reference',$cari);
        $query = $this->db->get('uhd_user_order');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

this is my view

```
                    <tr>
                        <th>No.</th>
                        <th>Customer Name</th>
                        <th>Product Code</th>
                        <th>Payment Type</th>
                        <th>Delivery Date</th>
                        <th>Total Price</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;padding-right: 15px;">Action</th>
                    </tr>
            <?php if($dapat !== NULL) { ?>
                <?php foreach ($dapat as $row => $test) {

                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?= $test->user_order_id?></td>
                        <td><?= $test->sender_name?></td>
                        <td><?= $test->user_product_order_id?></td>
                        <td><?= $test->payment_type ?></td>
                        <td><?= $test->time.$test->date ?></td>
                        <td><?= $test->delivery_price?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php }
            }else{
                echo "<td colspan='3'>no customer for the result!</td>";

            }
            ?>
        </table>
```

guys i need help here
im new in codeigniter. 
i need to make a search but the search result are needing 2 table from my database. `time`, `date` and `user_product_order_id` are from the `uhd_user_product_order`, and `user_order_id`, `sender_name`, `payment_type`, and `user_order_reference`(this the search key) are from `uhd_user_order`

in the view i can view it from my table uhd_user_order, but i cant view the `time`, `date` and the `user_product_order_id`

can you help me how to join the 2 table so i can see the best result from the search

Comment: nevermind i got it i have fix it

Comment: Can you please post your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code on your model

```
public function search($cari){

      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from("uhd_user_order AS t1");
      $this->db->join("uhd_user_product_order AS t2", "t2.user_order_id = t1.user_order_id");  # confirm user_order_id in both table
      $this->db->where('user_order_reference',$cari);
      $query = $this->db->get();
      return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function search($cari)
{
    $this->db->from("uhd_user_order AS t1");
    $this->db->join("uhd_user_product_order AS t2", "t1.user_order_id = t2.user_order_id");
    $this->db->where('user_order_reference',$cari);
    $query = $this->db->get('uhd_user_order');
    return $query->result();
}
```

become

```
    function search($cari)
    {
        $this->db->join("uhd_user_product_order" , "uhd_user_order.user_order_id = uhd_user_product_order.user_order_id");
        $this->db->where('user_order_reference',$cari);
        $query = $this->db->get('uhd_user_order');
        return $query->result();
    }
```